# jQuery combo box that fills the POST variable correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried several jQuery combo boxes (for example [the simple combobox plugin from jQuery](https://plugins.jquery.com/simpleCombobox/)) and remarkably they are all glorified selection widgets (i.e. you can select an item from a list with autocomplete, animations and whatnot) but not real comboboxes which would allow the user to select from a list but also **enter a value that is not in the list**.

(For the above mentioned plugin, even if you set the variable `invalidAsValue` to true it only sets the value internally and not in the field that is used in POST in a `<form>`, so if you have a list of "A" "B" "C" and the user enters "D", the result will be "A" because it will just use the preselection if it does not match an item.)

The HTML5/`datalist` feature (see [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)) is also not usable because it is very buggy in some browsers (in Firefox it is basically an autocomplete-feature and does only sometimes show the whole list, in Safari it is not supported at all) altough it is working correctly in Chrome.

I just want a basic combobox, as it exists in pretty much every graphics toolkit on earth since at least the early 1990s:

- An item is preselected
- The user may edit the item
- or choose an item from a drop-down list

There are many demos (including the above mentioned jQuery plugin) that fullfill the above three points, but I also need:

- Whatever the user has entered should appear in the HTTP-POST variable

(The URL-bar of any browser is an example of that widget: The user may choose from a list, but he may also enter an URL that is not in the list)

I don't need animations, skins or similar features, in fact I would prefer the most simple solution that is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Since this question is tagged with jQuery, I'm assuming your issue is parsing the combobox options to get the value correctly. Here's a pretty basic example of how to do this:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxybmhax/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        alert(
            $(this).children(':checked').html()
        );
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

It sounds like you're wanting to have values specified on the options though in which case you'd use `$(this).children(':checked').val()`.

Comment: There is no "checked" in a combobox. The reason why all these comboboxes are broken is because they are based on selection elements. I need to access what the user has entered, which is a string and not an option.